# How to associate object in sequelizejs using nodejs

Tags: node.js, orm

I don't understand how to associate object in sequelizejs.

I read doc (http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/associations.html#associating-objects), but I don't still understand how to use it.

Idea: I have object user and userlogin log. Its 1:M.

Example:

```
let dbUser = sequelize.define('user', {
    name: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
    },
    email: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
    },
    password: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
    }
});
dbUser.sync({ force: true })

let dbUserLoginLog = sequelize.define('userloginlog', {
    text: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
    }
});

//create 1:M relation to dbUser
dbUser.hasMany(dbUserLoginLog, { foreignKey: 'loginlog_pk' });
dbUserLoginLog.belongsTo(this.dbUser, { foreignKey: 'loginlog_pk' });

dbUserLoginLog.sync({ force: true })
```

Now, I can create user like this:

```
    dbUser.create({
                        name: req.body.name,
                        email: req.body.email,
                        password: hash
    });
```

How can I create dbUserLoginLog and add for specific user?
dbUserLoginLog is created every time, when user is logged to system.

Thank you for help!

Answer (score 0):

When association is defined, Sequelize will automatically add some methods for you. From the look of your code, I could use it like this:

```
dbUserLoginLog.create({/*...*/}).then((userLoginLog) => {
    dbUser.addUserloginlog([userLoginLog]);
});
```

For added method names, see: http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/associations.html#naming-strategy

Comment: I am getting `is not a function` when I call dbUser.addUserloginlog

Comment: I printed out all functions from dbUser instance and there is not any function with name addUserloginlog or somethink like this

Comment: You pass `this.dbUser` to `dbUserLoginLog.belongsTo`, I guess this could be the problem, remove `this` and try again